# Can Android malware cause any damage without any permissions?

Tags: malware, android, permissions

Just as the title says. On Android 6 you can control pretty much every single permission you give to an app. So my question is, if i give no permissions(i.e. when the app doesn't ask for them), is there anything malicious it could possibly do ?

It can't see/delete anything, it can't install anything so i think i am pretty safe(not talking about 0-days here) to install malware(this sounds too dumb to me but i really don't see any risks here.)

Comment: I think it would be best to assume that there's always a way to circumvent those systems.

Comment: That depends on what you define as "damage". For example, would it be "damage" to play embarrassing sound effects in public? Would it be "damage" to show offensive images to you? Would it be "damage" to just consume so many resources that other applications on your device become unresponsive?

Comment: It could just enter an infinite loop, forking as much as possible to use all cores, and prevent you from using any other app in a normal way. Maybe you won't even be able to uninstall it because the app manager would be unresponsive... Some 'guards' exist on android to prevent application freeze, but a carefully crafted one sending proper heartbeat to the system could really make your device unusable.